# Assemble structure and loop of an accordion

Tags: javascript, php

How do I get the names in the right IDs without repeating the ID name of the parent table?

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  $('.titulo').click(function() {
    var conteudo = $(this).parent().find('.conteudo');

    if (!conteudo.hasClass('show')) {
      $('.caixa').find('.show').slideUp('fast', function() {
        $(this).addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
      });

      conteudo.slideDown('fast', function() {
        $(this).addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

In PHP I use two tables, one that holds the title of my accordion, the table name is `temporadas`, this table contains the following fields.

**TABLE TEMPORADAS**

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL //auto increment
`id_serie` int(11) NOT NULL //identifies which ID to display my accordion
`id_temporada` int(11) NOT NULL //identifies the ID of my accordion
`nome_temporada` varchar(90) NOT NULL //name displayed on the accordion
```

**TABLE EPISODIOS**

My other table that holds the contents of my accordion calls `episodios`, and this table it displays its content as the `id_temporada` of my `temporadas` table is equal to the `id_temporada` of my table `episodios`, here it is my table.

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL //auto increment
`id_serie` int(11) NOT NULL //identifies which ID to display my accordion
`id_temporada` int(11) NOT NULL //identifies the ID of my accordion
`nome_episodio` varchar(100) NOT NULL //contents of my accordion
```

**PHP**

```
$url = explode("/",$_GET['url'],-1);
$url = $url[1];

if(isset($_GET['id_serie'])){
    $id_serie = $_GET['id_serie'];
}

$temporadas = "SELECT * FROM `temporadas` AS T INNER JOIN `episodios` AS E ON T.`id_temporada` = E.`id_temporada` WHERE T.`id_serie` = '$url'";
$temporadasShow = mysqli_query($conn, $temporadas);

while($show = mysqli_fetch_assoc($temporadasShow)){
    echo '
        <div class="caixa">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="titulo"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> '.$show['nome_temporada'].'</a>
            <div class="conteudo hide">
                  '.$show['nome_episodio'].'
            </div>
        </div>
    ';
}
```

**CSS**

```
.hide{display: none;}
```

My difficulty is that I cannot make the `nome_temporada` field of my `temporadas` table display only once, when it has more than one ID correpondent to it, it adds another name in the loop, how can I make it so it does not happen?

[image: element appears more, than one]

Comment: You must modify your sql script, and try to get data in such a way to show on screen.

Comment: @Abhishek Do you have any idea how to do this? can you use `LIMIT` for each ID?

Comment: Let me try, can you share your table data please. Just few rows.

Comment: @Abhishek the structures of the tables I use are those above

Comment: I can see schema, I need some example data, if you have.

Comment: @Abhishek http://scrashseries.rf.gd/seriado/9/dois-homens-e-meio here it is in operation with the problem that I can not solve, how many tables are these I put here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176300/discussion-between-rodrigo-and-abhishek).

Comment: Sorry, I've restricted access to URLs. Just create a fiddle for this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/141ee1/1

Answer (score 1):

SELECT T.id, T.id_serie, T.id_temporada, T.nome_temporada, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(E.nome_episodio) as nome_episodio
  FROM `temporadas` AS T
  INNER JOIN `episodios` AS E
  ON T.`id_temporada` = E.`id_temporada`
  WHERE T.`id_serie` = 2 GROUP BY T.id_temporada

you can use other aggregate functions like JSON_ARRAYAGG, JSON_OBJECTAGG etc. instead of GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: I added an `AND` to `SELECT`, it doubled the results of the second accordion, you know what I did wrong? `"SELECT T.id, T.id_serie, T.id_temporada, T.nome_temporada, GROUP_CONCAT(E.nome_episodio) AS nome_episodio FROM temporadas AS T INNER JOIN episodios AS E ON T.id_temporada = E.id_temporada WHERE T.id_serie = '$url' AND E.audio = 'Dublado' OR E.audio = 'Dublado'  GROUP BY T.id_temporada"` http://prntscr.com/k89p6l

Comment: SELECT T.id, T.id_serie, T.id_temporada, T.nome_temporada,
  GROUP_CONCAT(E.nome_episodio) AS `nome_episodio`
  FROM `temporadas` AS T INNER JOIN `episodios` AS E
  ON T.id_temporada = E.id_temporada
  WHERE T.id_serie = '$url' AND (E.audio = 'Dublado' Or E.audio = 'Dublado')
  GROUP BY T.id_temporada;
Could you try with brackets

Comment: in `sql` works perfectly, just ignoring the `audio` field on the site it pulls all together ignoring the `id_serie` that I changed the field in the database to` url` and even if I pulled it right I would need each one to be a link separated, each name `episodio_name` would correspond to a link

Comment: Can you provide updated schema of table and query again. Use JSON_ARRAYAGG, JSON_OBJECTAGG etc.